# HP ML350 Gen 8 - Can't install any OS

Tags: hp, windows-server-2016, windows-server-2019

Good afternoon,

I recently got myself an HP ProLiant ML350 Gen 8 server (with 6x3TB configured in RAID 5).
I intend to use this server for file storage and light CAD work.

My issue is that I can't manage to install any OS on this server. 
Here's what I have tried so far:

- Use the Smart Provisioning utility

  - Windows server essentials 2019 ISO on an NTFS USB drive : ISO not detected
  - Windows server essentials 2019 on a bootable USB drive : installer executable not detected
  - Windows server essentials 2016 ISO on an NTFS USB drive : ISO not detected
  - Windows server essentials 2016 on a bootable USB drive : installer executable not detected
- Boot override to USB drive

  - Both windows server essentials 2019 and 2016 won't partition the drive, giving me the error at the partitioning step :

```
windows cannot be installed to this disk. this computer's hardware may not support booting.
```

- Change SATA controller mode to AHCI: no difference
- Installation of Ubuntu server 2018: Installation complete, but unable to boot ubuntu server.

I am really ripping my hair off on this one... Any idea on how I could get it to work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Intelligent Provisioning are you using? Which RAID card?

Comment: Try latest intelligent provisioning version.  https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=MTX_a2b2caf8066e4a8b82a966d628

Answer (score 1):

After searching for a while, I finally found the solution.

In the SSA utility  > RAID controller > Properties > Advanced, you need to select a drive boot.

It was configured but not selected.

Now, Ubuntu server boots correctly, so I tried installing Windows Server Essentials 2019 and it worked.

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Amazing. Eventually this post solved my problem which I had been scratching my head about for a few weeks:
"
After searching for a while, I finally found the solution.
In the SSA utility > RAID controller > Properties > Advanced, you need to select a drive boot.
It was configured but not selected.
"

Comment: glad it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, there are 3 possible reasons:

1. BIOS Boot Mode
2. Hard disk protection is enabled.

**BIOS Boot Mode**
First of all, you should ensure the Boot Mode in your BIOS is set to Legacy BIOS instead of UEFI or vice versa.

**Remove Hard Disk Protection**
For the first situation, please read the specification or contact a sales person to confirm whether there is hard disk protection if the computer is not configured by ourselves. If there is, remove the protection by following the instructions.

**Note: Let me know if it will not resolve your issue**

Comment: This machine only supports BIOS, so I can't fail on this. 
I've already tried removing hard drive protection, but there is no such option on this server. 
I also tried changing the SATA controller mode but it turns out i'm dumb because 
- this server has SAS drives
- they are setup on RAID 5 anyway. 

I just found out that you can set a preferred boot drive in the RAID controller options, and managed to boot on Ubuntu server.

This, however, did not solve my issues regarding installation of windows server.